# Is it possible to make react-bootstrap-pagination always show pagination controls even if the total page count is 1?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, pagination, npm

I use [**Kurounin:Pagination**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-pagination) for MeteorJS and ReactJS.

Is it possible to make **react-bootstrap-pagination** always show pagination controls even if the total page count is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Kurounin/react-bootstrap-pagination/blob/master/src/pagination.js#L154), it seems that this is not currently possible with that package. Your options are:

1. Submit an issue or a pull request for the package to include an option to force showing pagination.
2. "Fake it" by adding custom HTML when there is only one page. This should be pretty close to the markup that the package would produce:

```js
{this.pagination.totalPages() > 1 ?
  <BootstrapPaginator pagination={this.pagination} limit={10} containerClass='text-center' />
:
  <div className="pagination-container">
    <ul className="pagination">
      <li className="disabled">
        <a href="#" className="previous-page" title="Previous page"> &lt; </a>
      </li>
      <li key="page1" className="active">
        <a href="#" className="page-link" title="Go to page 1"> 1 </a>
      </li>
      <li className="disabled">
        <a href="#" className="next-page" title="Next page"> &gt; </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Waiski!